# How Can I Convert \r \n to <p> with simple format in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Right now it just adds

```
\r\n\r\n
```

I'm trying to figure out how to convert

```
\r \n to <p> tags
```

The HTML gets posted to the DB via XHR, and post in firebug shows it like this:

```
html:

<html><head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=text/html; charset=utf-8>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<pre style=word-wrap:break-word; font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Tahoma; color:black>YADA YADA YADAYADA YADA YADAYADA YADA YADAYADA YADA YADA!\n\n YADA YADA YADAYADA YADA YADAYADA YADA YADAYADA YADA YADA.\n\nYADA YADA YADA\n\n&lt; via mobile device &gt;\n\nYADA YADA YADA &lt;xxxx@xxxxx.com&gt; wrote:\n\n</pre>\r\n<div>\r\n<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0 width=700 style=padding:0;>\r\n<tbody>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td colspan=2 style=color:#000000;font-size:11px;font-family:'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif valign=top>\r\n<div style=width:100%;font-size:12px;font-family:Helvetica;line-height:18px;>..... and it keeps going.
```

But when I use simple_format:

```
body = simple_format(@html)
```

I get this:

```
 <p>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<pre>YADA YADA YADAYAD........
```

Why isn't simple_format getting rid of the \r and \n and using paragraphs?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I would recommend using something like RDiscount or RedCloth

Comment: @Thomas, thanks can you share why?

Comment: This is HTML I'm getting from a Email Parse API, I don't control creating it.

Comment: oh ok, I though it was user input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be better off doing a string replace first:

```
@html.gsub!(/\r\n?/, "\n");
body = simple_format(@html)
```

This because simple_format only works on \n and \n\n, not \r\n:

[From the API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format):

> Returns text transformed into HTML using simple formatting rules. Two or more consecutive newlines(\n\n) are considered as a paragraph and wrapped in
>
> tags. One newline (\n) is considered as a linebreak and a 
>  tag is appended. **This method does not remove the newlines from the text.**

Comment: ok so where to go from here? I don't create the HTML it's delivered by SendGrid. I just need to clean it up and convert it?

Comment: I cleaned up the example (my original example used `gsub` instead of `gsub!` etc).